# how to set data type in textbox window forms

Tags: c#, winforms, types, textbox

I'm creating small app for private use. User will type an IP address in a TextBox and test whether it pings correctly.
It doesn't work because the TextBox is a WinForms Control  which can't be converted into bytes.

Is there any way to set top-down type of data in this TexBox?

```
System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ip_textbox.Text); 
OctetString community = new OctetString("public"); 
AgentParameters param = new AgentParameters(community); 
param.Version = SnmpVersion.Ver1; 
IpAddress agent = new IpAddress(ip_textbox.Text); 
UdpTarget target = new UdpTarget((IPAddress)agent, 161, 2000, 1); 
Pdu pdu = new Pdu(PduType.Get); 
pdu.VbList.Add(".1.3.6.1.4.1.2.1.1.2.0"); 
SnmpV1Packet result = (SnmpV1Packet)target.Request(pdu, param);
```

Comment: [IPAddress.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.tryparse). Strings need to be parsed to convert what they represent (for *human convenience*) to the actual type (as for numeric values, dates etc.). So you also verify that the input can actually represent the type (to validate it).

Comment: You must parse string value got from `TextBox.Text`.

Comment: Also you can google for IP-address textbox.

Comment: Can you share the code which tries to ping the IP address entered by the user!

Comment: well, thanks but i have already solved my problem. just tell me how to share code so i'll do it

Comment: So, you're using [SnmpSharpNet](http://www.docs.snmpsharpnet.com/current/index.html). This information should be part of the question. Your code also needs to be part of the question, don't use a comment for that. Btw, it looks like you cut out a piece of it, `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ip_textbox.Text);` is unassigned. What does *set top-down type* mean?

Comment: @Biurokles: if you want to share your solution, just write an answer to your own question.